# Homogeneous function in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

When we take an homogeneous function of degree $r>2$ which is not a polynomial in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d\setminus 0)$ why we eliminate zero?

There is no homogeneous function of degree $r>2$ which is not a polynomial  in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Comment: Could you give some context?

Comment: my question is the following is it possible to find an example of homogeneous function of degree $r>2$  which is not a polynomial in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Comment: I understand now, thank you.

Comment: Actually, I'm still confused by your question. Non-constant polynomials are not compactly supported, so there are no polynomials in the space that you mentioned, anyway.

Comment: you are welcom .

Comment: sorry i edited my post, there was a typo

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, consider the map $x\mapsto \left\lVert x\right\rVert^k.$ This function is smooth for $x\neq 0$, homogenous of degree $k$, and is not a polynomial.

For your second question, do you know the result that such a function satisfies $Df(x)x=rf(x)?$ Try to see if you can use this.

EDIT: I will sketch the result, but I will leave most of the details to the OP. The above tells us that the derivative of a function which is homogeneous of degree $r$ is homogenous of degree $r-1$ (differentiating $f(tx)=t^rf(x)$ yields $rt^{r-1}f(x)=Df(tx)x$). Similarly, the $k$th derivative is homogenous of degree $r-k.$ Use Taylor's theorem up to $r$ terms to obtain that $f(x)$ is the sum of $r$ functions, all homogenous of degree less than or equal to $r$, plus a remainder term. Taking the limit as $t\rightarrow 0$ will yield that $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: what is $r$ here?

Comment: The degree, like you used in your problem.

Comment: i dont see how to prove your equation

Comment: Differentiate both sides of $f(tx)=t^rf(x)$.

Comment: ok i see and why we need that equation?

Comment: You can use it with Taylor's theorem to get that $f$ must be a polynomial.

Comment: can you please detail that point in your answer? thanks in advance

Comment: @user640960 I have sketched the proof loosely for you, to encourage you to fill in the details yourself.